# Applying spread operator on object with getter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2018

If you declare a class with a getter

```js
class Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  get fullName() {
    return [this.firstName, this.lastName].join(" ");
  }
}
```

you can access the getter after instantiating a new object

```js
const person = new Person("Jane", "Doe");
console.log(person.fullName); // "Jane Doe"
```

but this won't work after copying the object using the spread operator

```
const personCopy = { ...person };
console.log(personCopy.fullName); // undefined
```

I think this is somewhat confusing syntax.

Comment: So you answered your own question within a minute.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was worth sharing. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Faizan [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Well `personCopy` is a plain object, it doesn't inherit a getter from `Person.prototype`. Why would you still expect `.fullName` to work?

Comment: @Bergi My point is that the syntax for two very different operations is identical and could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) only

> copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

While the property defined using the [get syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#get_Vs._defineProperty)

> will be defined on the prototype of the object.

Answer (score 3):

The spread operator creates a new object using `Object` as the constructor. So, in your case, `personCopy` is not the instance of class `Person` and as a result of this, its `__proto__` is not `Person.prototype` and therefore the getter won't work.